# Error when creating site from site template

Tags: managed-metadata, site-template, managed-metadata-service

I am having the exact issue here: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-IN/sharepoint2010setup/thread/76f96d55-6be2-4ad1-8da5-0b26a619c666

I saved a site as a template and then attempted to create a new site using the template and the error occurs: "The type of this column cannot be changed because it is currently being indexed."

However, when I go to Central Admin and click services > Managed Metadata Service it takes me to the Term Store Management setting page.

What am I missing?

thx
KS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get to those four checkboxes, highlight the MM Service Connection(just below the Managed Metadata Service), and select "Properties" from the ribbon.

Comment: When i click on it it redirects me to the termstore manager and I dont get a chance to click properties :S

Comment: click the row, but don't click the link itself.  Just like you would highlight a list item to make to ribbon appear.

Comment: Damn it! Still get the same error! Do you think i need to recycle app pool? I was hoping a user could create a subsite without having to do any of this :S

Comment: I can create a site from another template based on another website, but not this one. I see that this site has publishing feature activated but the other did not.

Comment: After a little more digging, I'm not so sure this has to do with Managed Metadata...  do you have any columns with indexes created?

Comment: I will take a look - do you mean the site from which the template was created? If so, I'll check it out thanks!

Comment: The site from which the template was created has a couple of indexes, one on a calendar list and another on a team discussion list. Would I need to remove these and re-create the template?

Comment: I would at least try that.  If it works you'll at least have an understanding of the source of the problem.  If not you can cross it off the list of potential issues.

Comment: Ok, I think it's not working because the site is of type Publishing - which doesnt seem to be supported. thanks for your help